# How to enable remove file in favorites block of PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to configure right mouse click menu in PhpStorm to enable deleting of file from `favorites block` as it enabled in `project block` and not use `safe delete`?

Comment: I'm not sure about a context menu item, but simply pressing the "Delete" button on your keyboard will remove it from the favorites.

Comment: on "MAC OS X"  DELETE and COMMAD+DELETE do nothing

Comment: I just confirmed this working on OS X with just delete (don't use the command key). Tested on the latest version 2016.1.1 build #PS-145.970.

Comment: PhpStorm 2016.1 Build #PS-145.258 + El Capitan don't want to remove on delete button press, http://i64.tinypic.com/261ogsz.png - it is my menu preview when I click in favorites

Comment: Same issue in PhpStorm 2018.3.4 on macOS Mojave. "Delete" is not in the context menu and the shortcut "⌫" does not work.